# Please use "relativetime" class on timestamps in comments

Tags: feature-request, design, timestamps

Small bug/feature request: The "relativetime" class is not used in comment timestamps.

While I was writing [this Greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12635/greasemonkey-script-to-display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time), I noticed that the relative timestamps in the comments are not tagged with the "relativetime" class, the way relative timestamps are everywhere else on the site (i.e. questions, answers, user profile, question lists).

**Edit**: Found one more place where the class isn't being used:  on the message for a bounty, stating "this question has a bounty of X expiring in Y days".  Also, in that case the timestamp tooltip is in ambiguous m/d/yyyy format, which could be interpreted by some users as d/m/yyyy.  The yyyy-mm-dd format would be more consistent with the rest of the site.

Comment: Kip, this really isn't a bug.  Using inconsistent code behind the program isn't a bug if the program (website in this case) behaves as it is supposed to.

Comment: well it's not really a "feature" either

Comment: Touche...I guess it is a 'design-request'

Comment: @jjnguy YOU'RE WRONG. DESIGN INCONSISTENCIES ARE BUGS EVEN IF INTENTIONAL http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/code-window-adds-vertical-line-before-text

Comment: Umm...but not if the untended user can't see the difference and everything works as planned.

Comment: @IAN ELLIOT: ALL CAPS IS FUN, BUT PLEASE DONT'T USE IT!!!!!!

Comment: I was definitely kidding :(

Comment: Well, now no one knows I was yelling at you cuz you changed your name to some bizarre name of a celebrity.

Comment: @jjnguy I think he just changed it to his real name.  Ian Elliot was a pseudonym.